# Implement C Callback in Objective-C

Tags: ios, c, block

Im using SDK (Linphone) written in C, and I need to implement call state change handler function declared in C file into objective-C or best in Swift environment.

Here is the declaration in C:

```
// declaration
void call_state_changed(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *msg);

// typedef
typedef void (*LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb)(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *message);
```

Here the struct containing the property for LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb that is needed to implement

```
typedef struct _LinphoneCoreVTable{
   LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb call_state_changed;/**<Notifies call state changes*/
} LinphoneCoreVTable;
```

Here is my attempt:

```
_vTable->call_state_changed = ^(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *message)
{

}
```

Here is the error:
[image]

What's the correct syntax for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to implement, because C code *just* runs fine in Objective-C?

Comment: Do not post code as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use a *block*, when all you need is a (possibly `static`) C-function, as follows:

```
static void _linphoneCallback(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call,
                              LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *message)
{
    // do thing
}

...
_vTable->call_state_changed = _linphoneCallback;
```

However I cannot see how you'd pass an Objective-C class instance to the callback, making the callback difficult to use in any language, including C.

Comment: I will just use notificationcenter, all I need is the cstate value. Will it possible?

Comment: @Hokage Yeah I would say so.

Answer (score 0):

Define the callback like this 
`typedef void (^LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb)(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *message);`

And use it:
`LinphoneCoreCallStateChangedCb callback = ^(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneCall *call, LinphoneCallState cstate, const char *message){};`

Comment: The callback is not a block.

Comment: Ah you are right. I was thinking that he want to correct the block syntax.